# How can I change the Apple ID that Xcode 4 uses to download components?

Tags: xcode

I am running Xcode 4.2 on OS X 10.6.8.

Due to corporate policy, I have two Apple ID's. `me@bigcorp.com` is my "work" ID, and that's the ID that is connected to my iOS Developer Program membership. I also have `me@personalmail.com`, my "personal" ID, which is associated with my music, Angry Birds download, and so on.

I'm trying to install the iOS 4.3 Simulator from within Xcode (Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components). When I click the "install" button next to that component, Xcode complains that `me@personalmail.com` is not a "Registered Apple Developer". I'd like to have it use `me@bigcorp.com`, but I can't find any reference anywhere that describes how to change it, within Xcode or otherwise. Can anyone explain how to beat Xcode into submission?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can change the Apple Developer ID that Xcode has associated using Mac OS X's Keychain Access app:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Open Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access
3. Locate the Keychain entry named "daw2.apple.com ([your Apple ID])" of kind Internet password
4. Delete this Keychain entry and retry the download in Xcode by re-entering your credentials, or double click on the entry and update the Account and Password fields
5. Open Xcode and retry the content download

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I ever would have thought to look there.

Comment: What happened to "Things are so easy on a Mac!" ?

Comment: Worked for me, although I also deleted a buch of developer signings/certificates too just to be sure! :D + 1

Comment: The only daw2.apple.com that I have is of type "Web Password". In fact I have no "Internet passwords" at all. Are these the same thing?

Comment: Has anyone filed a bug to apple? Seriously, I can't get "another" version of a free thing because I used another email to download it the first time. This makes no sense!!

Answer (score 5):

It's 2014 and I still got this answer by searching the error that pops up.

If you're using Xcode 5+, you can go to Xcode > preferences > accounts and add as many dev accounts as you would like.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not help. Had more success with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395077/updating-xcode-using-different-apple-account