# XCode won't let me change my login details

Tags: xcode

Xcode states.

xxxx@gmail.com is not a Registered Apple Developer.

This is really annoying, as I have a registered account, I just typed the wrong one. How to I get another opportunity to login.

Comment: where are you getting this error from?  documentation or when you are trying to code-sign an app or?

Comment: It's the downloads section of the Xcode preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the documentation links in that preference pane and then click on "check & install now" button again.

That should bring you back to the login dialog.

Comment: I'm downloading components. Not documentation.

Comment: Are you there, this is rather urgent.

Comment: I'm trying to Download the command line tools and I inserted the wrong login details. I have the correct ones, but Xcode won't let me use my new login details. How do I give it my new login details?!

Comment: Ummm, if you want instant help, you should go to the [iPhone / iPad chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad).  But in general, you really need to have some patience (and time) to solve problems. Sure, everything is urgent, but problem solving isn't always instant gratification.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions from this similiar question might work, they just did for me:

[How can I change the Apple ID that Xcode 4 uses to download components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997317/how-can-i-change-the-apple-id-that-xcode-4-uses-to-download-components)

It seems it's better to download Xcode directly from Member Center (not trough the Mac App Store).

Comment: @Rollo Montgomery Konig-Brock: i'm not sure if your question is a duplicate of the one that i linked. If it is please mark it as such.