# Updating XCODE using different apple account

Tags: xcode, macos, upgrade

I have MAC OS 10.7.3. xcode 4.3.1 installed using different apple id as my macbook pro was used previously by my friend. Now when i try to upgrade Xcode to 4.3.2 it asking credentials for my friends account. Unfortunately App store clearly says you can upgrade an app  using the account which was used to install the app.

How can i upgrade Xcode using my credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997317/how-can-i-change-the-apple-id-that-xcode-4-uses-to-download-components "this") can interest you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately had to answer my own question, 
Simple Answer: NO, You cannot update xcode installed from another account.
Solution is to delete the existing installation and re-installing from new account.
To delete the existing installation, you need to delete it from Launch pad. You can do this by locating xcode icon in launch pad, long click on the icon till it starts dancing. Then delete it and wait for a while till the xcode.app is deleted from /Application. If you manually delete xcode.app from /Application, App store will continue to think its installed and will not allow you to reinstall in future.

Above solution is assuming you have installed xcode from the mac app store, usually versions later than 4.2. For earlier versions, just deleting /Application/xcode folder should work.

Comment: It seems to vary.  @Venkat's solution did not work for me, but this one did.  Though in my case I had to use a third-party app to delete Xcode from LaunchPad.  You should've seen the email sent to Apple support before finding this thread ... I doubt they'll be happy about the threat to replace OS X with Slackware Linux, but the response should be funny.

Answer (score 52):

I am sure you would have solved this by now but just posting the solution here that worked for me..

1. Open Finder and navigate to Applications,
2. Ctrl+Click the application and choose "Show Package Contents" (Xcode in this case),
3. Expand the Contents directory and click the _MASReceipt directory to select it, Type Command+Delete to
   delete the directory permanently---you will be prompted for your
   credentials since this is a protected file.
4. Quit and restart
   AppStore, then find the application. You can update with your new id now without deleting the old version of the app

Hope this helps someone coz it took me a while to figure out !!

Comment: I can't find the directory. I'm trying for XCode 5. Is it different than the prev version?

Comment: which directory are you talking about ? For me, _MASReceipt seems to be present in Xcode 5 as well..

Comment: On OSX 10.9.5, upgrading XCode 6.0 to 6.1 this still works. Thank you @venkat!

Comment: im using Xcode 6.1 cant find this  _MASReceipt folder

Comment: Working perfectly for me, Thanks @venkat

Comment: This still works for XCode version 8.3.2. Thanks, @venkat!

Comment: Did it for XCode 8.3.2 but on High Sierra. Deleted _MASReceipt but that also removed XCode from the update list, meaning it made no difference if I just deleted the app.

Comment: Xcode 9.2 -> Not able to make the update. It does a fresh install instead

Comment: Big Sur, updating XCode 12. Same result as dor506. Didn't need to "uninstall" but it does download a fresh copy. But at least I have the latest version now.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is found:

I had this bug, it's related to Spotlight. The App Store used Spotlight in some way. My     fix was to add the entire HD to the "Privacy" tab in the Spotlight System prefs pane, close the prefs and wait 30 seconds, re-open and remove your HD from the Privacy tab. Spolight begins reindexing. Re-opened the App Store and problem was fixed! Posting this here for others who might search later on. Also filed a bug report with Apple.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2806858?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks for the info. The scenario in which i faced the issue was different, it was actually installed from different account.

Comment: No problem. I think there are many people with absolutely the same issue and your scenario.

Comment: This worked for me (10.10.3, Xcode 5 -> 6.3) after trying the solutions from suresh and venkat. Per venkat's instructions, I deleted the _MASReceipt folder which allowed me to attempt a different Apple ID, but I couldn't work around the "Update Unavailable with this Apple ID" error. Deleting Xcode.app and rebuilding the Spotlight index worked.